# Travel to the US as a tourist while being independent contractor

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas, medical-tourism

I'm a software dev working as an independent contractor for an US company remotely from my country of origin (Venezuela) and I have to travel to US as a tourist to receive a medical treatment using the B2 medical treatment/tourist visa.

My question is, will I be able to continue working for that company as a contractor while I stay in US for my treatment (paying taxes of course) or would be impossible for me to obtain the visa and travel there when they find out about my job?

I cannot afford to lose this job but I really need that surgery to continue living, I appreciate any info you can give me about my case.

Comment: If you "really need that surgery to continue living" then whether you can work or not isn't strictly relevant. Perhaps you should focus on the best case for obtaining your visa, with **no intention of working**, then you can tell the complete truth and not be fearful of being 'found out' and not receive the surgery. Please see [B-2 Visa for U.S. Medical Treatment: Who Qualifies](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/b-2-visa-us-medical-treatment-who-qualifies.html).

Comment: Canada explicitly allows visitors to work remotely for foreign employers while they visit Canada.  If you cannot afford to stop working while you recover from the procedure, you may want to investigate whether you can obtain the treatment in Canada and, by extension, recover there.

Comment: Are you contracted directly with the US company, or is there some kind of intermediary - even a one-person corporation - registered in your home country?